# Why is the sign of $L^2$ opposite?

Tags: lie-algebras

The following figure is from an [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casimir_element) about Casimir element of Wikipedia. According to the following, $L_x^2$ is not a simple matrix multiplication of $L_x$ with itself, since the sign is opposite. It is a multiplication in the universal enveloping algebra. But exactly what caused this sign change?

[image]

Comment: There's a sign change that might occur coming from the fact that the Killing form is negative rather than positive definite. But I just don't agree with this calculation as written; if you write $L_x^2$ then you should mean $L_x^2$.

Comment: I came up with this question, since I thought there would be some convention such that $L^2_x$ is defined as $L^t_xL_x$, which means multiplication of the transposed matrix and the original one. Otherwise the identity doesn't seem to hold. Likewise, if I don't assume the above convention, Casimir element of $\mathcal{so(3)}$ becomes $-\frac{1}{2}(L^2_x+L^2_y+L^2_z)$, which has an incorrect sign.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In such cases it might help to visit the talk page as well, because other users might have run into the same issue.

There is a discussion about this issue [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:Casimir_element#example:_so.283.29).

Comment: Great suggestion. I haven't come up with that idea!

Comment: I am sorry that I can not judge the argument given there. My next stop would have been some advanced text on quantumn mechanics, which treats angular momentum.